# What is the difference between list1[0] and print(list1[0]) in python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between 'python' & python?
We get outputs in different forms for accessing the elements of a list.
Print statement returns output without single quote.[image]

Comment: You're executing in a REPL which automatically prints out for you. Also, that's a "single quote", not an "inverted comma".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of the python REPL - when using python interactively, the returned value of whatever statement you run (as long as it is not `None`) gets printed to the console.

Since `list1[0]` returns the string `'python'` and there's no more statement after that, the string gets printed. If you're running the same line in a script (not interactively), then it wouldn't print anything.

`print()` specifically prints to the console, and will do so regardless of whether python is running in interactive mode or not. It also formats the output *to be printed* - it doesn't print "what the element is", it prints "what you tell it to print". Which is why the single-quotes aren't there. `print()` doesn't need to say that it's a string.